# Javascript select all radio button by once

Tags: javascript, php

I've following php table where 2 radio button exist. One is **Present Student** and another is **Absence Student**. So now there are a option to select all radio button by once but ti's select all right side and left side radio button. I want to select only left side radio button which is Present All. May be javascript function is not correct.

```
$action = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."?class=$class_from";  
echo "<form method='post' action='$action' name='attendence'/>";

echo "<table width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='tdhead' valign='top' width='200'><b>Student Name</b></td>";    
echo "<td class='tdhead' valign='top' width='250'><b>Roll No</b>
</td>";             
echo "<td class='tdhead' valign='top' width='250'><b>Class Name</b>
</td>";             
echo "<td class='tdhead' valign='top' width='200'><b>Present student / absence student</b>
</td>";                 
echo "<td class='tdhead' valign='top' width='200'>
Present All <input type= 'checkbox' onclick='checkAll( this )'</td>";
echo "</tr>";

//start the counter variable
$counter = 1;
while ( $res2 = mysql_fetch_array( $sql2 ) ) {
   $id = (int) $res2['id'];
   $sname = inputvalid( $res2['sname'] );
   $roll = inputvalid( $res2['roll'] );
   $class = inputvalid( $res2['class'] );

   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>$sname</td>";
   echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>$roll</td>";
   echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>$class</td>";
   echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>";

   //echo each radio with the counter for this row
   echo "<input type='radio' name='ch[$roll][$sname][$class]' value='1' />&nbsp;";
   echo "<input type='radio' name='ch[$id][$sname][$class]' value='0' />";

   echo "</td>";
   echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>&nbsp;</td>";
   echo "</tr>";

   //add one to the counter
   $counter++;
}

echo "<tr>";                
echo "<td class='tdhead2'>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td class='tdhead2'>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td class='tdhead2'>&nbsp;</td>";             
echo "<td class='tdhead2'>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td class='tdhead2'><input type='submit' value='Record' name='Submit' 
class='submit' /></td>";                
echo "</tr>";               

echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";


if ( isset( $_POST['Submit'] ) && $_POST['Submit'] == "Record" ) {
   if ( isset( $_POST['ch'] ) ) {
       $ch = array_filter($_POST['ch']);
       if ( empty( $ch ) ) {
          echo "<div class='error>Select attendence field. </div>";   
       }
   }

   if ( count( $ch ) == 0 ) {
       echo "<div class='error>Select attendence field. </div>";    
   } else {     
       foreach ( $_POST['ch'] as $roll => $arr1 ) {
       $roll;
       foreach ( $arr1 as $name => $arr2 ) {
           $name;
           foreach ( $arr2 as $class => $value ) {
              $class;
              $value;
              $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO e_attendence VALUES('', '$name', '$roll', '$class', '$value', '$current_date')");
           }
       }
    }
}

if ( $sql )         
   echo "<div class='success'>Succesfully recorded.   
</div>";                                    

}
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
<script language="javascript">
   function checkAll( master ) {
       var checked = master.checked;
       var col = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
       for ( var i = 0; i < col.length; i++ ) {
           col[i].checked= checked;
       }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: remove `language="javascript"` for starters.

Comment: assign different ids to radio button and use getElementBYId in Javascript to select them

Comment: @Alex which You want? jquery or javascript?

Comment: @vishalshah no, no. No.

Comment: @ripa Javascript is better

Comment: Stop using `mysql` it is deprecated. Start using `mysqli` or even better (imo) `PDO`. Stop using inline events (`onclick`) - also an outdated and bad practice. Use javascript to attach events. And soooo many `echos` :( use the syntax found in the accepted aswer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564130/difference-between-if-and-if-endif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for javascript , use below:-

```
first modify the "radio" button code with below:-

echo "<input type='radio' name='ch[$roll][$sname][$class]' class='pres' value='1' />&nbsp;";
echo "<input type='radio' name='ch[$id][$sname][$class]' class='abse' value='0' />";
```

now use below javascript **for all left side "radio"**

```
function checkall(el){
var ip = document.getElementsByClassName('pres'), i = ip.length - 1;
for (i; i > -1; --i){
    if(ip[i].type && ip[i].type.toLowerCase() === 'checkbox'){
        ip[i].checked = el.checked;
    }
}
}
```

and use below for all "right side radio":-

```
function checkall(el){
var ip = document.getElementsByClassName('abse'), i = ip.length - 1;
for (i; i > -1; --i){
    if(ip[i].type && ip[i].type.toLowerCase() === 'checkbox'){
        ip[i].checked = el.checked;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I can this with : Present All <input type= 'checkbox' onclick='checkall(this)'</td>";  but it's select all radio button both right and left side.

Comment: left side radio button means?

Comment: @Alex yes I found that. Check my edited answer. that will work for You

Comment: both javascript function has same function name, is it right ?

Comment: check properly and obviously You try to apply Your common sense. The above solution will work 100% according to Your question. But how You are using the answer that matters. stackoverflow is not the place for wasting time.